# Jquery script don't work on loaded page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

In my web-application i have a div which loads another page: `$('#main').load('pages/main.php');`

main.php consists jquery validation script. This script is working if i go directly to the main php, but don't work if i will use this page on my index page where main.php loaded.

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Fiddler/Firebug to watch the HTTP requests and see the response. Post that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using .livequery() to solve EXACTLY this issue! :)

have a look.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/

Include the plugin, then you'll need something like this in your index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#yourInputField') 
              .livequery(function() { 
                 $('#yourInputField').YourValidatorPlugin(); 
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks. But, i will use .live() - which is build in analog of livequery

Answer (score 1):

as Inrbob points out the problem is that loading content into an element will not load nor execute script elements. The appropriate way to apply a new script to the page is to implement:

```
var s = $("<script src='" + script_location_for_validation + "'/>");
$("body").append(s);
```

This will lazy load the javascript and keep your code out of your page (important if you want to use caching to improve speed on later page loads).

As an aside it is very good practice to put your libraries and scripts at the end of your page so they do not block other downloads or rendering.

Comment: I had some trouble getting this to work in all IEs but I was pulling back scripts from the head and the body; some were external files, some inline. If this method works for you (i.e. you always know what scripts are on the page you are pulling) you can add the code to the .load() callback so that the script will run as soon as the data is loaded.

Comment: @lnrbob in all the projects I have been working in lately IE6 is being considered a millstone that has finally been shed. IE7 and IE8 should handle it correctly.
@dsplatonov as lnrbob implied if you do not have control of the code on the other side of the request you this solution doesn't do anything for you.

Answer (score 1):

very easy

1. Save all javascript functions used main.php in external file and include it in current page.
2. Load content in to div.
3. Call the appropriate function.

It will surly work.

Answer (score 0):

.load() doesn't pull back scripts. This is part of the default functionality in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)